# Convert JSON to Avro schema in Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, converters, avro

I wanted to convert CSV to Avro schema in Nodejs. I was able to convert CSV to JSON and now trying to convert JSON to AVRO schema. Is there any package available in nodejs.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful. This will allow you to encode / decode avro binary format to / from json format, it supports both deflate and snappy compressions and supports node streams

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-avro-io